# Graph classes equivalent to circular-arc graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for properties of [circular-arc graphs](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_133.html), mainly its equivalence relations with more common graph classes. Simular to properties such as $\mathit{interval} \equiv \mathit{chordal} \cap \mathit{cocomparability}$, $\mathit{interval} \subset \mathit{circular\_arc}$

Comment: You might find the book Graph Classes: A Survey, A. Brandstadt, Van Bang Le and Jeremy Spinrad published by SIAM, 1999, of use.